# How to test if a player is running in 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a map where the player can't stop running or they die.

I've searched around a bit and all the answers I found are similar to making some sort of scoreboard value like:

```
/scoreboard objectives add run stat.sprintOneCm
```

but that doesn't seem to be working. I know 1.13 changed a lot of commands so I don't know if it's just 1.13 or if I'm doing something wrong but it'd be nice to know how do it.

Comment: I can think of a clumsy method that might work but would also involve building an architechture in the map and wouldn't just be a scoreboard method...
would that suit your needs?

Comment: That scoreboard objective is outdated. Use /scoreboard objectives add run minecraft.custom:minecraft.sprint_one_cm